# How to put a comma in addressfield display?

Tags: 8, forms

I'm using the address module with Drupal 8.x. I want a comma in the each line of the below address. Currently addresses display like:

John Peter
1181 Broadway
New York
SW1A 1AA
United Kingdom

I want it to display like:
John Peter,
1181 Broadway,
New York,
SW1A 1AA,
United Kingdom.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you would need to write a custom `address-plain.html.twig` file and add it to the `templates` folder either in a module or in your theme.

Code:

```
<p class="address" translate="no">
  {% if given_name or family_name %}
    {{ given_name }} {{ family_name }}, <br>
  {% endif %}
  {% if organization %}
    {{ organization }}, <br>
  {% endif %}
  {% if address_line1 %}
    {{ address_line1 }}, <br>
  {% endif %}
  {% if address_line2 %}
    {{ address_line2 }}, <br>
  {% endif %}
  {% if dependent_locality.code %}
    {{ dependent_locality.code }}, <br>
  {% endif %}
  {% if locality.code or postal_code or administrative_area.code %}
    {{ locality.code }} {{ postal_code }} {{ administrative_area.code }}, <br>
  {% endif %}
  {{ country.name }}.
</p>
```

Comment: FWIW you consider marking up the address using one of the techniques here: https://iandevlin.com/blog/2012/01/html/marking-up-a-postal-address-with-html/

Comment: That's really interesting, thanks for the link.
I just used the template file that the module ships with and added the formatting changes @Kiran requested, since that seems to me to be the simplest solution.